# Firebase Remote Config & A/B Testing with real time updates

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I've implemented real time remote config updates via the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime).

In general, it works as expected, except when it comes to experiments via A/B Testing. Changes to A/B Testing that affect remote config do not fire the update cloud function hook.

Does anyone know if its possible to have the `functions.remoteConfig.onUpdate` cloud function hook trigger when a change to remote config is made via an A/B Testing experiment change?

The only workaround I can think of is to have a dummy value in remote config itself that I change whenever an experiment is created/updated.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is nothing built into Remote Config for that at the moment. But thanks to the [integration between Cloud Functions and Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/rc-events), you can build it yourself.

One of our engineers actually just gave a demo for this last week. I recommend you check it out here: https://youtu.be/lIzQJC21uus?t=3351.

In this demo, there are a few steps:

1. You publish a change from the Remote Config console.
2. This change [triggers Cloud Functions through a `functions.remoteConfig.onUpdate` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/rc-events#trigger_a_function).
3. The Cloud Function [sends an FCM message to all apps through a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic).
4. When an app receives this message, it shows a prompt that the configuration is out of date.
5. When the user clicks the "fetch" button, the app [fetches the new configuration data from Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#fetch-andactivate-values-from-the-service-as-needed).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've successfully implemented by following the docs. My issue is specifically that changes to A/B Testing experiments that would result in remote config changing (for some users at least) does not trigger the `functions.remoteConfig.onUpdate` event.

Comment: Sorry about that, I completely missed that we had documented this precise process: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime. I'm actually not sure how A/B testing updates are pushed to Remote Config (and thus to Cloud Functions). Let me ask around.

Comment: The answer was fast, but unfortunately negative: the Cloud Function will only be triggered once a winner has been chosen. A/B Testing update before that do not trigger Cloud Functions.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how does realtime update work for remoteconfig if app in killed state?

Comment: If the app is not active, it will update the next time it is started.